# Listen for an event on python and parse though the data

Tags: python, json, slack-api

I am a designer, and have been given an potentially impossible task to learn python, like right now, from my boss.

Currently I have a python script that has connected a websocket between Slack and our server that retrieves json data that is sent to a user bot on Slack.

here is the code:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from websocket import create_connection
import requests
import json
import sys

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        url = (json.loads(requests.get("https://slack.com/api/rtm.start?token=xxxxxxx").content))['url']
        s = create_connection(url)
        s.sock.setblocking(0)
        while True:
            try:
                print s.recv()
                #self.stdout.write("{}\n").format(s.recv())
            except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
                sys.exit()
                raise
            except:
                continue

c = Command()
c.handle()
```

here is an example of the json data I am retrieving:

```
{
 "type":"message",
 "message": {
        "type":"message",
        "user":"U045XDV70",
        "text":"<#C08SY155G> <http://seedinvest.com>",
        "attachments":[
                {"title":"SeedInvest",
                 "title_link":"http://seedinvest.com",
                 "text":"SeedInvest is an equity crowdfunding platform that connects accredited investors to vetted startups and small businesses seeking funding.",
                 "fallback":"SeedInvest",
                 "thumb_url":"https://d2v4u62fw1nf2w.cloudfront.net/app/img/website/logo_square_200.png",
                 "from_url":"http://seedinvest.com",
                 "thumb_width":200,
                 "thumb_height":200,
                 "id":1}
                 ],
        "ts":"1443638877.000008"
        },
 "subtype":"message_changed",
 "hidden":true,
 "channel":"D0BBF1JJG",
 "event_ts":"1443638878.008753",
 "ts":"1443638878.000009"
 }
```

Now, my next task is to:

- Listen for a "message" event
- when a "message" event comes in with an "attachment"
- parse the message looking for channel markers, for example:<#C08SY155G>
- then re-post that "attachment" to that channel.

I am getting a lot of direct from the Slack API, however, writing it in Python is a whole other animal, and I am not sure where to get started, or in what section to attempt to start writing something.

Any sort of direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So for some direction, when you import a json object, you can use it as you would any other dictionary object. So looking for a "message" you would look for it as ["type"] and check for values.

Answer (score -1):

[ijson](https://pypi.org/project/ijson) (available through pip) might be helpful, which is a python wrapper for [yacl](https://lloyd.github.io/yajl) (available through conda)

Example

```
import ijson

parser = ijson.parse(urlopen('http://.../'))
stream.write('<geo>')
for prefix, event, value in parser:
    if (prefix, event) == ('earth', 'map_key'):
        stream.write('<%s>' % value)
        continent = value
    elif prefix.endswith('.name'):
        stream.write('<object name="%s"/>' % value)
    elif (prefix, event) == ('earth.%s' % continent, 'end_map'):
        stream.write('</%s>' % continent)
stream.write('</geo>')
```

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.